# changing a lists sort order inline

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list
Each row has a common input field "sort_order" that's stored in MySQL db.

```
 <input name="sort_order" type="text" value="<?php echo $cat['sort_order']; ?>" size="3" />
```

I want to be able to change the sort order inline, without going into the edit form.

How do I get all the values into the database. I think I need to loop through each row adding the sort_order[row_id] and value to an array. But I am stuck on how to achieve this.

all the values are posting according to firePHP. sort_order[50] 1, sort_order[51] 2 etc.

New Attempt at explaining:

I have a list view with 2 input fields.

```
<input name="cat_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cat['cat_id']; ?>" /> 

<input name="sort_order" type="text" value="<?php echo $cat['sort_order']; ?>" size="3" />
```

I have a function that's called on post in the controller:

```
public function sortOrderUpdate(){


//collect the values of cat_id and sort_order from each input into a array
//$this->request->post['sort_order']
//$this->request->post['cat_id']

//send to the model

$this->model_cat->updateCatSortOrder($sortorderarray);


}
```

And the database model file function:

```
public function updateCatSortOrder($sortorderarray){


foreach((int)$sortorderarray as $sort){
$this->db->query("UPDATE cat SET sort_order='" . (int)$sort['sort_order'] . "'  WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$sort['cat_id'] .  "'");
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: can you clearify your question somehow? what's is your fields in DB and what do you want to show exactly? sorry that i can't get your problem!

Comment: I have a list view. I want to be able to edit the 'sort_order' column value in the database from the list view.

Comment: do you already have some code for saving the values in the db? it would also be very interesting to see your db structure!

Comment: I have a list view. I want to be able to edit the 'sort_order' column value and save to the database from the list view.I have a button at the top of the column that posts the column values. But i don't know how to retrieve these values in my function updateSortOrder() into an array. The array will then be sent to a mySQL update function in another file. Probably not a much better explanation , but i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to work:

```
<input name="cat_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cat['cat_id']; ?>" />
<input name="sort_order[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $cat['sort_order']; ?>" size="3" />
```

Controller:

```
    public function updateCatSortOrder(){

            $sortvals = $this->request->post['sort_order']; //$this->request->post  same as $_POST 
    $row = $this->request->post['cat_id'];
    $n = count($this->request->post['cat_id']);
    $sortorder = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){

        $sortorder[] = array(
        'cat_id' => $row[$i],
        'sort_order' => $sortvals[$i]
        );
    }


    $this->model_cat->updateCatSortOrder($sortorder);
            }
```

Model:

```
 //UPDATE CAT SORT ORDER    
 public function updateCatSortOrder($sortorder){
    foreach($sortorder as $sort){
    $this->db->query("UPDATE cat SET sort_order='" .   $this->db->escape($sort['sort_order']) . "' WHERE cat_id = '" . $this->db->escape($sort['cat_id']).  "'");
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [empty square brackets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays):

```
<input type="text" name="sort_order[]" value"<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" />
```

You can then access the input as an array, saving you from building it yourself. It'll be stored as `$_POST['sort_order']` (or `$_GET`, depending on the method attribute specified in your `<form>` tag).

On a related note, you should probably escape `$sort_order` when echoing it:

```
<input type="text" name="sort_order[]" value"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sort_order); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i would not recommend using [ ] in html names.

```
<input type="text" name="sort_order_<?php echo $row_id; ?>" value"<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" />
```

say, you have 50 input fields, when posted, you can build an array this way:

```
$sortorder = array();
for($i=0; $i<50; $i++){
    $sortorder[] = $_REQUEST['sort_order_' . $i];
}
```

Comment: is this right?
$sortorder = array();

for($i=0; $i < count($this->request->post['sort_order']); $i++){
    $sortorder[] = $_REQUEST['sort_order_' . $i];
}

$this->model_shelters_cat->updateCatSortOrder($sortorder);